# why didn't we use a stack here ? Interleaving String- Leetcode

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack

I understood that we can use dynamic programming here but my first intuition was to use stack since s3 is made up of substrings of s1 and s2 so i concluded that the order of occurrence of characters of s1 and s2 will be same in s3 that is LongestCommonSubsequence(s1,s3)=s1 and LongestCommonSubsequence(s2,s3)=s2 and thats why I though I could just compare the characters of s3 with stack values and pop characters if they are same (i maintained 2 stacks and pushed s1 and s2 in reverse order ) if s3 is interleaving both stacks must be empty in the end and we can return true (i have attached my code,it could be wrong but thats what i was trying to do)

i cant seem to visualize where this approach would fail, if anyone has any idea please share your thoughts I'm really struggling
thanks in advance !

```
  
bool isInterleave(string s1, string s2, string s3) {
        stack<char>a,b;
        for(int i=s1.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
            a.push(s1[i]);
        }
         for(int i=s2.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
            b.push(s2[i]);
        }
      
        int i=0;
        while( i<s3.length()){
            int flag=0;
            while(!a.empty() &&i<s3.length()&& a.top()==s3[i])
            {
                a.pop();
                i++;
                flag=1;
                
            }
            while(!b.empty()&&i<s3.length()&&b.top()==s3[i]){
                b.pop();
                i++;
                flag=1
            }
            if(!flag)i++;
            
        }
        
      
        return (a.empty()&&b.empty()&& i==s3.length()?true:false);
    }
```

Comment: Example input that will cause your solution to fail: `s1='aacc'` `s2='ccbb'` `s3='aaccbbcc'`

Comment: btw: the `for` loops need to start at `length() - 1`

Comment: @user3386109 my bad i actually modified the code a lot of times so didn't notice the errors, i have rectified them so I'll update it and thanks for the test case it made me realize what i was doing wrong!!